# Using IF - ELSE in SQL Server Insert Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to use IF-Else in Insert Query in sproc. I have tried this code, and getting error.
What's wrong?

```
    create procedure sp_m_ii_2_kaydet
@mtu int,
@mod int,
@moid int,
@uid int
as
insert into m_ii2_alisfatura 
(muhtur, mturid, muhodm, modmid, uid) values 
(@mtu, 
IF (@mtu = 3) SELECT MAX(id) FROM m_ii1_vsf_personel
ELSE IF (@mtu = 2) SELECT MAX(id) FROM m_ii1_vsf_firma
ELSE IF (@mtu = 4) SELECT MAX(id) FROM m_ii1_vsf_taseron, 
@mod, @moid, @uid)
```

Comment: You can do that with if condition. which version of sql server are you using? Check my answer..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not a valid syntax try this

You need to use three different insert statements

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Sp_m_ii_2_kaydet @mtu  INT,
                                  @mod  INT,
                                  @moid INT,
                                  @uid  INT
AS
    IF ( @mtu = 3 )
      INSERT INTO m_ii2_alisfatura
                  (muhtur,mturid,muhodm,modmid,uid)
      SELECT @mtu,Max(id),@mod,@moid,@uid
      FROM   m_ii1_vsf_personel
    ELSE IF ( @mtu = 2 )
      INSERT INTO m_ii2_alisfatura
                  (muhtur,mturid,muhodm,modmid,uid)
      SELECT @mtu,Max(id),@mod,@moid,@uid
      FROM   m_ii1_vsf_firma
    ELSE IF ( @mtu = 4 )
      INSERT INTO m_ii2_alisfatura
                  (muhtur,mturid,muhodm,modmid,uid)
      SELECT @mtu,Max(id),@mod,@moid,@uid
      FROM   m_ii1_vsf_taseron
```

or Use `union all` by filtering the data in where clause

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Sp_m_ii_2_kaydet @mtu  INT,
                                  @mod  INT,
                                  @moid INT,
                                  @uid  INT
AS
    INSERT INTO m_ii2_alisfatura
                (muhtur,mturid,muhodm,modmid,uid)
    SELECT @mtu,Max(id),@mod,@moid,@uid
    FROM   m_ii1_vsf_personel
    WHERE  @mtu = 3
    UNION ALL
    SELECT @mtu,Max(id),@mod,@moid,@uid
    FROM   m_ii1_vsf_firma
    WHERE  @mtu = 2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT @mtu,Max(id),@mod,@moid,@uid
    FROM   m_ii1_vsf_taseron
    WHERE  @mtu = 4
```

or even `case` statement

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Sp_m_ii_2_kaydet @mtu  INT,
                                  @mod  INT,
                                  @moid INT,
                                  @uid  INT
AS
    INSERT INTO m_ii2_alisfatura
                (muhtur,mturid,muhodm,modmid,uid)
    SELECT @mtu,CASE
             WHEN @mtu = 3 THEN (SELECT Max(id)
                                 FROM   m_ii1_vsf_personel)
             WHEN @mtu = 2 THEN (SELECT Max(id)
                                 FROM   m_ii1_vsf_firma)
             WHEN @mtu = 4 THEN (SELECT Max(id)
                                 FROM   m_ii1_vsf_taseron)
           END,@mod,@moid,@uid
```

**Note :** First two queries will not insert any record if atleast one condition is not matching. But the case statement will insert data will null value even though none of the condition is matched

Comment: So, i can't use IF-Else in Insert's parameters..?

Answer (score 0):

infact **you can do that** with similar syntax if you are using SQL server 2012 or later version..

**Eg:**

```
create table #tt(Id int)

create table #tu(tid int)
insert into #tu values(1),(2)

declare @test int = 1
insert into #tt
values (iif(@test=1,(select min(tid) from #tu),(select max(tid) from #tu)))

select * from #tt
```

**Your query modified**

```
  create procedure sp_m_ii_2_kaydet
@mtu int,
@mod int,
@moid int,
@uid int
as
insert into m_ii2_alisfatura 
(muhtur, mturid, muhodm, modmid, uid) values 
(@mtu, 
IIF (@mtu = 3, (SELECT MAX(id) FROM m_ii1_vsf_personel),IIF(@mtu = 2,(SELECT MAX(id) FROM m_ii1_vsf_firma),
IIF(@mtu = 4,( SELECT MAX(id) FROM m_ii1_vsf_taseron),0))),
@mod, @moid, @uid)
```

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2014 and with first answer, i got wrong MAX(ID) values.

Answer (score 0):

I am getting wrong MAX(ID) values with this combined code;

```
    ...procedure [dbo].[sp_m_ii_2_kaydet]
@mtu int,
@mod int,
@uid int
as
declare @mtuid int
declare @modid int
if (@mtu = 3 and @mod = 1) 
set @mtuid = (select MAX(id) from m_ii1_vsf_personel)
    set @modid = (select MAX(id) from m_kasa_personel);
if (@mtu = 3 and @mod = 2)
set @mtuid = (select MAX(id) from m_ii1_vsf_personel)
    set @modid = (select MAX(id) from m_hesap_personel);
if (@mtu = 3 and @mod = 3)
set @mtuid = (select MAX(id) from m_ii1_vsf_personel)
    set @modid = (select MAX(id) from m_senet_personel);
if (@mtu = 3 and @mod = 4)
set @mtuid = (select MAX(id) from m_ii1_vsf_personel)
    set @modid = (select MAX(id) from m_cekcikis_personel);
if (@mtu = 2 and @mod = 1) 
set @mtuid = (select MAX(id) from m_ii1_vsf_firma)
    set @modid = (select MAX(id) from m_kasa_firma);
if (@mtu = 2 and @mod = 2)
set @mtuid = (select MAX(id) from m_ii1_vsf_firma)
    set @modid = (select MAX(id) from m_hesap_firma);
if (@mtu = 2 and @mod = 3)
set @mtuid = (select MAX(id) from m_ii1_vsf_firma)
    set @modid = (select MAX(id) from m_senet_firma);
if (@mtu = 2 and @mod = 4)
set @mtuid = (select MAX(id) from m_ii1_vsf_firma)
    set @modid = (select MAX(id) from m_cekcikis_firma);
if (@mtu = 4 and @mod = 1) 
set @mtuid = (select MAX(id) from m_ii1_vsf_taseron)
    set @modid = (select MAX(id) from m_kasa_taseron);
if (@mtu = 4 and @mod = 2)
set @mtuid = (select MAX(id) from m_ii1_vsf_taseron)
    set @modid = (select MAX(id) from m_hesap_taseron);
if (@mtu = 4 and @mod = 3)
set @mtuid = (select MAX(id) from m_ii1_vsf_taseron)
    set @modid = (select MAX(id) from m_senet_taseron);
if (@mtu = 4 and @mod = 4)
set @mtuid = (select MAX(id) from m_ii1_vsf_taseron) 
    set @modid = (select MAX(id) from m_cekcikis_taseron);
insert into m_ii2_alisfatura (muhtur, mturid, muhodm, modmid, uid) values
(@mtu, @mtuid, @mod, @modid, @uid)
```